# JavaFX's AudioClip(Media) not playing sound in Raspberry PI 3

Tags: javafx, raspberry-pi, gluon, javafxports

I can't make any sound with JavaFX's **AudioClip** in **RaspberryPI** 3.

```
AudioClip audioClip = new AudioClip(this.getClass().getResource("/musics/arcade.wav").toExternalForm());
audioClip.setVolume(0.3);
audioClip.setCycleCount(AudioClip.INDEFINITE);
audioClip.play();
```

Currently using:

> **jdk-8u144-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt** - JDK
>
> **armv6hf-sdk-8.60.9** - GLUON

And having done this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42085226/6562856

After doing the above it doesn't throw any Exception, but it doesn't emit any sound.

Should I use another 'sound' API?

EDIT:

**.mp3 files are working, .wav aren't.**

Comment: Are other (java) applications able to output audio?

Comment: I found out that .mp3 sounds work. The problem are .wav files.